# SQL Developer error Unable to find Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

After installing `Oracle 11g` client, when I tried to run `SQL Developer` it's asked me to give it `java.exe` path. As I didn't know I gave it the wrong path to program files java installation.

Which I later found out that I should have given the path to `java.exe` inside oracle folder.

Now every time I run it doesn't ask me for java.exe path, but shows the next error: `Unable to find Java Virtual Machine`.

I think to correct this I need to give Java path to it in oracle folder, but how to change the path that I have already given?

Comment: If you would be a [maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) you wouldn't ask questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I faced a similar issue and i fixed it by following steps:

step1: Go to where your SQL Developer is installed.

step2: Go into the sqldeveloper folder (inside SQL developer installation folder) >bin

step3: just edit the  sqldeveloper.conf .

```
   You will see line called “SetJavaHome”, that’s where we need to fix.

    Remove that line, then try starting the SQL Developer again:
```

use this [link](http://zhengshenyu.com/2013/08/20/unable-to-find-a-java-virtual-machine/) for further references.

Comment: After editing the sqldeveloper, i got prompted again for Java.exe location. I was able to select the Java.exe from sdk folder and was able to continue. Thanks

Comment: I have installed the 32 bit version and then set the path it didn't work then i installed the 64 bit version of it and it work fine.

Comment: This got solved setting the following line in sqldeveloper.conf
SetJavaHome D:\app\<my username>\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdk
Its starts and can connect.