# SQL Developer 17.2 - Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer version 4.2.0.17 is set up on a computer I'm using (I'm using Windows).

The folder for that version contains a jdk folder and the SQL developer runs fine.

I downloaded SQL Developer 17.2 and unzipped the file. When I went to run the .exe I was asked to confirm the location of the jdk on the computer.

At that time, I didn't realise that the jdk folder was already in the folder for SQL Dev 4.2.

There is also an 'OraHome_WF' folder on the c:\ drive, which contains a jdk folder, so I confirmed that was the location of the jdk folder when first launching SQL Dev 17.2.

Now when I launch SQL Dev 17.2 I get an error message:

> Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine Location at path: C:\OraHome_WF\jdk\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll

I looked in the 17.2 folder to see if there were any config or settings files that might have been updated after I put the wrong jdk path in, so I could point to the correct jdk folder, but I can't see anything.

I tried deleting the 17.2 files and unzipping the 17.2 folder again, but when I launched SQL Dev I got the same error without being asked where the jdk folder is located.

Is there any way I can work around this problem?

I already tried this workaround:
[SQL Developer error Unable to find Java Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008395/sql-developer-error-unable-to-find-java-virtual-machine)

Comment: I guess you are running it on Windows. If yes then go to `%APPDATA%\SQL Developer` subdirectory, then remove  a subdirectory which name contains a version number of your SQL-Developer,  like `system 17.2.xxxxxx`. This will erase all program's settings. And then run it again.

Comment: try copy MSVCR100.dll file from \jdk\jre\bin to the sqldeveloper\bin folder

Comment: Thanks for your replies... I tried the 2nd option, to copy the .DLL file to `sqldeveloper\bin` but that hasn't fixed it. I tried the 1st option (I'm using Windows, sorry - edited the question to state that) - there are folders there called `SQLHistory`, and `system4.2.0.17.089.1709` and `tmp` but no foldfer for 17.2...

Comment: However! There was folder `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper` - and that contained a `17.2.0` folder - deleted that, and could then point to the correct location. So problem fixed. Thanks!

Comment: It's strange. [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.2/RPTIG/installing-sql-developer.htm#RPTIG127) says, that SQL Developer user preferences should be located in: `Windows: C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\systemn.n.n.n.n` folder. Mayby your `%APPDATA%` environment variable points to another location.

Comment: @krokodilko - it's working now thanks - There was folder `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper` - and that contained a `17.2.0` folder - deleted that, and could then point to the correct location. So problem fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.2/RPTIG/installing-sql-developer.htm#RPTIG127), user preference settings are located in the following locations:

> **SQL Developer user preferences**
>
> Windows: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\SQL
>   Developer\systemn.n.n.n.n
>
> Linux or Mac OS X: ~/.sqldeveloper/systemn.n.n.n.n

Removing this subdirectory should fix the problem (and in this case it fixed it).

Comment: Just to clarify - in this case, even though using windows, the folder I had to delete was in `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\17.2.0` rather than in `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\17.2.0`. Sounds like I'm being picky - just wanted to clarify that in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue for Jdeveloper. Apparently the latest jdk does not have the msvcr100.dll file. I resolved it by previous jdk version Jkd 8u221 which has this file and it ran successfully